# SELECT * when access to some columns is prohibited

Tags: postgresql

I have a table `tbl` with column-level grants where columns `a` and `b` are readable by everyone but column `c` is only readable by certain roles.

Currently, `SELECT * FROM tbl` fails for non-privileged users with `ERROR:  permission denied for relation c`. Is there some way I can make the statement return just columns `a` and `b` instead of failing?

I know `SELECT *` is generally discouraged, but this table is used by data scientists who do a lot of ad-hoc queries, either directly in SQL or via various tools that connect to the table.

I know I could create a view, but the table is much more complicated than the example. There are 20-30 columns with different combinations of role access, so it would result in at least as many views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define a view on top of this table:

```
CREATE VIEW tbl_view AS (
    SELECT a, b
    FROM tbl
)
```

Then, have the data scientists hit this view with a `SELECT *`.  I'm assuming that in practice there are more columns than just `a` and `b`.  The idea here is that you do the heavy lifting of spelling out the allowed columns, so your consumers do not have to worry about this.

Comment: Thanks. I just added an explanation that, yes, the actual table is more complicated and has many rows with many different roles assigned. So creating views is doable but painful.